# Laravel foreach select only show options with the same id

Tags: php, laravel

So what the problem is, is that the extraoptions foreach works, but it shows all the `eos_name` fields, and not only the fields that have the same `eos_extra_id`.

how i want it to work:

i want to have the first select to only show `eos_name` fields with the 
`eos_extra_id` of 30, and then when another checkbox comes in, i want that select to show `eos_name` where the id is one higher.

sorry if i didn't explain it well..
anybody know how to fix this? thanks in advance!

**html**

```
<label>Opties</label>
<br>
@foreach($options as $option)   
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox"
            class="option"
            id="option_{{ $optie->exa_id }}"
            name="option_{{ $option->exa_id }}"
            value="{{ $option->exa_id }}"
            {{
                isset($cache)
                    ? (isset($cache['option_' . $option->exa_id]) ? 'checked' : '')
                    : (
                        old()
                            ? (old('option_' . $option->exa_id) ? 'checked' : '')
                            : ($registration
                                ? (
                                    in_array($registration->exa_id, $registration_options)
                                        ? 'checked'
                                        : ''
                                )
                                : '')
                        )
            }}>
            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $option->exa_price }}" class="option_price_{{ $option->exa_id }}">
            <label>{{ $option->exa_name }}</label>
            <label>  €{{ $option->exa_price }}</label>
    </div>
    <select name="extraoptions" class="form-control">
        @foreach($extraoptions as $extraoption)
            <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_id }}">{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

**RegistrationController**

```
//options
$options_ids_array = array();
$options = Extra::all();
foreach($options as $option){
    $option->exa_id = "option_" . $option->exa_id;
    $input_option = $option->exa_id;
    if(!is_null($input_option)){
        $options_ids_array[] = $input_option;
    }
}

$registration->dev_option_id = implode(",", $options_ids_array);
$registration->save();

//extra options
$extraoptions_ids_array = array();
$extraoptions = ExtraOptie::all();
foreach($extraoptions as $extraoption){
    $extraoption->eos_id = "extraoption_" . $extraoption->eos_id;
    $input_extraoption = $extraoption->eos_id;
    if(!is_null($input_extraoption)){
        $extraoptions_ids_array[] = $input_option;
    }
}

$registration->dev_option_id = implode(",", $extraoptions_ids_array);
$registration->save();
```

Comment: Can you show the tables structure for these tables

Comment: Can you show the tables structure for these tables

Comment: the extra options table has eos_name and eos_extra_id, and the extra table has exa_name and exa_price. in the form you go from extra to extraoptions. so for example: you click on the extras and fill in "T-shirt" and 40, then go to extraoptions and fill in: L, M, XL, S

Comment: so you just want that when a user select product, then under this he will get a option to choose the size, and store the id of this product with size in the extraoptions table. Am i correct???

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but try and let me know what happens

In Controller

```
public function view()
{
$options = Extra::all();
$extraoptions = ExtraOptie::all();
return view('yourbladefrom',compact('extraoptions','options'))
}
public function store(Request $request)
{
$option = new Extra;
$options->name=$request->name;//your product name
$options->price=$request->price;//your product price
$options->save();
$extraoptions = new ExtraOptie;
$extraoptions->eos_id=$request->eos_id;
$extraoptions->save();
}
```

In view

```
@foreach($options as $option)
            <input type="checkbox" id="check" value="{{ $option->name }}">{{ $option->name}}</option>
@endforeach
<select name="eos_extra_id" class="form-control" id="select">
        @foreach($extraoptions as $extraoption)
            <option value="{{ $extraoption->eos_extra_id }}">{{ $extraoption->eos_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

And use a jquery for this

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#check").on('change',function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#select").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("#select").prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

try this and let me know or if i getting something wrong also let me know

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, and it still showed all exa_names in the select unfortunately. I did have the extra and extraoptions given to the index. What im also working on is that when you select a checkbox, it adds the price of that item to the price input i also have in the form. Not sure what to do now, you have any other ideas? also i dont really know what the jquery is doing

Comment: Jquery is for when you select a product then a dropdown will appear for choosing the size

Comment: And yes it will show you the all names because we paas the variable that will contain all result.

Comment: Oh ok, you have an idea of how i show only the exa_names where the eos_extra_id goes from lower to higher? i want every other eos_name select to show another eos_extra_id.

Comment: sorry cant understand, what do you mean by lower to higher and also can you explain little bit more what are tring to say by this "i want every other eos_name select to show another eos_extra_id".

Comment: When you fill in the name of the exa_name in de 'Extra' form (for example T-shirt or socks) and the exa_price, you can see all the extras you have added, and on each extra you can go to their extraoptions, and there you add different options for that extra you clicked on. for example you make T-shirt an extra and XL, L, M, S the extra options(the eos_name). But ofcourse all the extraoptions(eos_name) come in the database. thats why there is an eos_extra_id in the extraoptions table. now the extraoptions at the different extras have different eos_extra_id's.

Comment: Also, each time you add an extra(exa_name and exa_price), it adds a checkbox with the exa_name in the registration form. also in the form: there is a foreach for the extraoptions, but it shows all the extraoptions(eos_name). so it shows (S, L, M, XL and green, red, blue). green red and blue have the same eos_extra_id and S, M, XL, L have the same eos_extra_id. but in every select it just shows all extra options